# Linux block devices naming

Tags: linux, devices, disk

I am a bit confused with how linux hard drive/ storage device, block files are named.

My questions are:

- How are IDE devices and partitions named?
- How are EIDE devices and partitions named?
- How are PATA devices and partitions named?
- How are SATA devices and partitions named?
- How are SCSI devices and partitions named?

Lastly, I have been reading articles on this subject, and I have seen mentions of 'master drives' and 'slave drives'. What are these, what are they used for, and how are they named?

Comment: Note that (E-)IDE and "PATA" are just different names for exactly the same thing. In fact, there's nothing that would be officially called "PATA", that's just an alias for IDE that people started using because it nicely mirrors "SATA".

Comment: What about ssd devices ? Or other solid state drives? On my laptop I have /dev/nvme0n1p5. And raid devices I think are named /dev/md* (multi device)? Is there a good reference or overview/wiki for how linux devices are named ?  Like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Naming_conventions but is not comprehensive .. yet ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Introduction

First of all, all the devices populate the `/dev` folder.

Also, it is important to note that (E)IDE and PATA terms usually refer to the same thing, which is the [interface standard PATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA). IDE and PATA are interchangable terms in this context.

There was a major change in naming conventions for block devices in Linux, around the release of Linux kernel version 2.6. The kernel supports all ATA devices through [libATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibATA), which started with SATA devices support in 2003 and was extended to current PATA support.

Therefore, be aware that, depending on your distribution and kernel version, the drives naming convention can differ.

Since a while, PATA devices on "modern" distributions are named the ways SATA drives are, since both are now using libATA.

---

For your distribution, you can find this in `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`.

On my system using Debian 9, it is also the case. For example:

```
$ cat /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules | grep "ATA"
# ATA
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", 
ATTRS{vendor}=="ATA", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $devnode"
```

By browsing this file, you will know how your distribution will name every block device you could connect to your machine.

### Block devices naming conventions

#### IDE drives

- IDE drives (using the old PATA driver) are prefixed with "hd"

  - the first device on the IDE controller (master) is `hda`
  - the second device (slave) is `hdb`

Since there can only be two drives on one IDE controller/cable, the master is the first one and the slave is the second one. Since most motherboard are fitted with two IDE controllers, it goes on the same way with the second controller:`hdc` being the master drive on the second controller and `hdd` the slave drive.

**Be aware that, since Linux kernel 2.6.19, the support of IDE drives has been merged with SATA/SCSI drives and, therefore, will be named like them.**

#### SATA and SCSI drives

This naming convention started with SCSI drives, and was extended to SATA drives with libATA. It applies to SCSI, SATA, PATA as well as others drives, out of the scope of OP question (USB mass storage, FireWire, etc.). Anyway, usually, all the devices using a serial bus use the same denomination nowadays (except for NVMe drive, but this would a story for PCI devices).

- SATA/SCSI drives start with "sd"

  - the first one is `sda`
  - the second one is `sdb`
  - etc.

### Partitions naming conventions

Regarding partitions, each of them is denoted by a number at the end of each disk, named as described previously, **starting from 1**. Except for some other devices not mentioned in OP, it is always the case.

By instance, for the partitions on a SATA drive, they would be listed as `sda1`, `sda2`, and so on, **for primary partitions**. Logical partitions start at the index "5", while the extended partition takes the index "4". Note that this is obviously only true for drives making use of MBR and not GPT.

Below, this is the output of `lsblk` giving an example for disk called `sdd`, with 3 primary partitions (`sdd1`,`sdd2`,`sdd3`), 1 extended partition (`sdd4`) and 2 logical partitions (`sdd5`,`sdd6`).

```
$ lsblk
sdd      8:48   1   1.9G  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   1   153M  0 part 
├─sdd2   8:50   1   229M  0 part 
├─sdd3   8:51   1   138M  0 part 
├─sdd4   8:52   1     1K  0 part 
├─sdd5   8:53   1   289M  0 part 
└─sdd6   8:54   1   1.1G  0 part
```

### Master and slaves devices

A single IDE interface can support two devices. Usually, motherboards come with dual IDE interfaces (primary and secondary) for up to four IDE devices on a system.

To allow two drives to operate on the same parallel cable, IDE uses a special configuration called master and slave. This configuration allows one drive's controller to tell the other drive when it can transfer data to or from the computer. The name comes from the fact that the slave drive ask the master if it is communicating with the motherboard; if the master is, it will tell the slave to wait until the operation is finished but if not, it will tell the slave to go ahead.

The master/slave role could be chosen thanks to the "Cable Select" feature: you could use a jumper on each drive supporting this feature to select either "Master", "Slave" or "Auto" (this last option meaning that the master is at the end of the IDE cable and the slave is the other).

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i really appreciate the help, this is a good answer as it answer's all my problems and questions, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Yep its pretty clear but one thing i gotta ask, do partitions ALWAYS start with 1 or 0? Also are master and slave devices only associated with IDE devices, or is there another interface such as PATA or SATA/SCSI which master and slave devices can exist on?

Comment: Always with 1 for drives. Only notable exceptions being floppy disks and CD/DVD devices where devices/partitions can be mixed up.

Comment: Also are master and slave devices only associated with IDE devices, or is there another interface such as PATA or SATA/SCSI which master and slave devices can exist on?

Comment: Master/slave pattern derives from the fact that it uses a parallel interface which ATA/ATAPI protcoles. Thereferore, it impacts all PATA connexions such as IDE, EIDE, Fast ATA, Fast IDE, Ultra ATA, etc. SATA making use of a single serial interface, there is no reason for this feature to exist for SATA.

Comment: @TooTea That's why the last paragraph is for, and why I started with "historically". Would it be better to stress it more?

Comment: This is because of iterating changes asked through comments that I ended up with that answer, and why I was asking OP if it was clear (because it does not seem so to me). I will try to make clearer but if you already have something in mind, feel free to edit it in the meantime.

Comment: @TooTea mabye you could submit an answer which outlines how they work nowadays

Comment: @TooTea I started to rewrite it to make it clearer; please, let me know what you think.

Comment: its pretty good man, even better and much clearer than before thanks once again man ! :)

Comment: Paradox i am a bit confused about what you said about the linux kernel update in kernel update 2.6. could you please tell me what happend and what changes were made as i am a bit confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92115/discussion-between-qasim-and-paradox).

Comment: @Paradox this is somewhat minor, but I get the impression you’re mixing things up a bit on the SCSI side. `libata` doesn’t support SCSI devices, and “Fast”, “Ultra” etc. all refer to SCSI variants (Fast SCSI, Ultra SCSI, Ultra160 etc.), not IDE (as in your comment above).

Comment: @StephenKitt Problem is, usually, when it comes to Linux, a "SCSI device" is any device that uses the Linux SCSI subsystem and this often includes SATA disks. From Linux kernel > ~2.6.24, there is an alternate SCSI passthrough driver called "bsg" (block SCSI generic). Feel free to improve my answer but I had trouble putting together a good summary between what OP did not (and still does not) understand and what anyone could find interesting without being an encyclopedia. I think 3 whole iterations were necessary to achieve this "draft", a new pair of eyes is more than welcome.

Comment: @Paradox I tried to clarify that side of things in your answer (and yes, I realise it’s hard). On the purely SCSI hardware side of things, the driver is still `sd` (or `sr` for CD-ROMs etc.), which doesn’t use `libata`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yeah, I mixed up some stuff when trying to simplify. Especially it's not that easy to explain (part of) the architecture, especially since, even e.g. SATA drives can use the SCSI subsystem. Feel free to edit my answer if you already know how to improve it. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Found an [old reference](https://www.debian.org/releases/etch/amd64/apcs04.html.en) which refers to everything but SATA.

SATA & SCSI drives are */dev/sd**X*** where starts with ***a*** to refer to the physical drive.
Partitions are */dev/sdX**Y***  where ***Y*** represents the partition number (beginning with 1) within that device.

EIDE device naming was the same as IDE is the same as PATA, before Linux kernel 2.6.19 (Thank you, [Paradox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/159254/paradox), for noting the change!)
/dev/hda was the 'master' drive on the 'primary' controller.
/dev/hdb was the 'slave' drive on the 'primary' controller.
/dev/hdc was the 'master' drive on the 'secondary' controller.
/dev/hdd was the 'slave' drive on the 'secondary' controller.
A number follows each drive device to denote the partition(s), beginning with 1.

Since Linux kernel 2.6.19, the same naming convention as SCSI & SATA is used for EIDE, IDE, and PATA.

Comment: SATA drives and USB thumb-drives are handled by the SCSI driver, so the reference still applies. The order (which disk `sda`) is derived from how the controller enumerates the disks (depending on the hardware, the order may change every boot). Hot-plugged devices usually are assigned the first unused letter (though you and the kernel may have different opinions on which letters are still in use).

Comment: The partitions do not start with "0" but "1" usually.