Find out if any part of a disk is mounted or in use?
I need to confirm that no part of a disk is mounted before over-writing the entire disk. The problem here is that it seems that you have to know the names of any filesystems on the disk before checking them individually, and this might in general be difficult.
As an example, the system I'm writing this on has an SSD, and parted -l shows this disk as /dev/nvme0n1, size 500G. /dev/block shows:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Nov 18 12:37 259:0 -> ../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   12 Nov 18 12:37 259:1 -> ../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   12 Nov 18 12:37 259:2 -> ../nvme0n1p2

Minor number 0 is then the 'whole disk', while 1 is the boot partition, and 2 is the swap partition. This SSD is set up for LVM but the LVM devices have completely different /dev/mapper names.
The word nvme0n1 doesn't appear anywhere when you check for mounted filesystems (mount, findmnt nvme0n1, /proc/mounts, /etc/mtab). The word nvme0n1p1 does appear, but only because it's a mounted boot partition (/boot/efi). In general, the disk I'm looking at might not have a boot partition, so searching for nvme0n1 as a prefix might not be helpful (and even if I found a word with the correct prefix, am I guaranteed that it's on the same drive?)
Is there any generic way of finding out if a disk is 'in use'? In this particular case, I can parse the lsblk output to find the /dev/mapper names under nvme0n1, but this doesn't seem like a good long-term solution.

if you run this it shows partitions & mount points: lsblk -f see also man lsblk

@oldfred: unfortunately, this doesn't actually give any more useful information than plain lsblk: you still have to walk down through the children of a 'disk' (part, lvm, whatever) and check whether any of them have a mountpoint.


(and even if I found a word with the correct prefix, am I guaranteed that it's on the same drive?)

Yes, the prefix literally indicates which drive it is – nvme0n1 is NVMe device 0 namespace 1, and all nvme0n1p## partition devices are named that way because they're on this specific drive.

Is there any generic way of finding out if a disk is 'in use'? In this particular case, I can parse the lsblk output to find the /dev/mapper names under nvme0n1, but this doesn't seem like a good long-term solution.

It's not bad, as lsblk has code to determine both direct mounts of partitions, as well as device-mapper relationships – and even mdraid relationships, which are a separate thing from device-mapper.  I don't think there can even be a truly generic solution without resorting to tools like lsblk that know how to gather this information from several disparate places.
Instead of parsing its regular output, run lsblk --json and parse that, finding your disk and descending into its .children attribute recursively, until you find one with a non-empty .mountpoints.
But even lsblk doesn't know about Btrfs multi-device filesystems, for example (showing a mountpoint only under one of the devices), and it knows even less about ZFS.

I'm currently working on parsing it with jq... slow-going.

Check /etc/mtab, a kernel-genrerated list of everything that is mounted. man mtab.
Read man lsof, especially the whole entry starting with

+D D This option causes lsof to search for all open instances of directory D and all the files and directories it contains to its
complete depth.

and do something like
sudo lsof +D <mountpoint>

for each mounted filesystem.
Also, just in case, check with swapon or cat /etc/swaps, another kernel-generated file.

The problem with this is that mtab (or mount/whatever) doesn't contain the overall disk device (/dev/nvmen01 in my example). You still have to parse the lsblk output to find potentially completely different devices which are on the same disk (/dev/mapper/some-name). I'm looking for a way to do this without going through the parsing hassle.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510778/linux-block-devices-naming . If you regard stripping off the partition names as "parsing hassle", your script-fu lacks completeness. It's regarded as an "easy" level problem.
